# Waiting function It is necessary to synchronize

Tags: c#, wait

Is there any waiting function in c#?  More precisely I want do something after changing a `bool` variable. It is necessary to synchronize the download files from a web server with `webClient.DownloadFileAsync`? I know about the `webClient.DownloadFile` method, but it can't show me the downloading status.

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For examle i have two files 1.mp3 and 2.mp3. I call function downloadfile(1.mp3) from server, and before ending this download I should ban downloadfile(2.mp3). Only after successfull downloading 1.mp3 I can call  downloadfile(2.mp3). I need fucntion which will be wait succesfull downloading.

Comment: Since [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is **blocking**, a similiar solution to that given by @darthmaim would be to add all files for example to a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then iterate over all items and download the corresponding file using WebClient.DownloadFile - this will not start downloading 2.mp3 until 1.mp3 is not ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the [WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx). Add the files you want to download to a Queue, and once the DownloadFileCompleted gets called, start the next download.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about what you want, but I assume you'd like to check when the download is finished and that could be achieved by 'hooking' (not quite sure about what to call it :p) the DownloadFileCompleted event in the class WebClient, could be done like this;

```
WebClient wC = new WebClient();
wC.DownloadFileCompleted += wC_DownloadFileCompleted;
wC.DownloadFileAsync("url", "path to save location");
```

(If you're getting an error at the second line, which you will, choose the error fix telling you to create a method, assuming you're using VS)